# Please explain this proof of AM-GM inequality

Tags: algebra-precalculus

[I don't undeestand this proof](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZTJ5K.jpg)

How does rhis proof work? What does it mean when it says "Since every time we perform this
operation we create a number equal to A"? Is it taking averages?

Answer (score 0):

By "create a number equal to $A$, the author means that each time you apply the process, the new sequence that you get ($a_1',a_2',\dots$) has one more term equal to $A$ than the previous sequence ($a_1,a_2,\dots$). Since there are only $n$ terms in the sequence, the process can be applied at most $n$ times before all the terms are equal to $A$.

Comment: Thanks!! But won't there be n/2 terms equal to A? Since we take pairs (a1, a2), (a3,a4).......in each iteration. Could you please tell me how it'll be proven?

Comment: @EHN Nothing prevents us from taking $(a_2,a_3)$ is one of these is $<A$ and the other is $>A$.  As long as not all the terms afre equal to $A$, at least one will be $<A$, at least one will be $>A$, and so the process can again be applied.

Comment: Lets say there are even number of terms, in the last pair we have one term A & another A+h-k, so in the end won't we have (n-1) A terms?

Comment: @EHN Since the average remains $A$ at all stages, once you have $n-1$ terms equal to $A$, the one remaining term will necessarily also be equal to  $A$.

Comment: Yes i get it now, thanks!!